# Scroll Bar is not Working in Android

Tags: android-layout

I want to display 5 graphs in a singe screen,I have Added scroll bar view,but its not working for me. Could you please help us.Below is my Code .
This is my XML file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i have 4 liner Layout to display the graph .And one main layout which will contain all the 4 linear layout.

Comment: Can you please put your Java file where you are adding your graphs in LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

try this codes this will work perfectly for you

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />
</LinearLayout>
```